# Dictionaries vs key/value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I understand that a dictionary refers to a collection of key/value pairs, but I’m confused on a few of the finer details.

Does a dictionary need to contain more than one key value pair? Example 1:

```
person = {'first_name': 'John’}
```

Is this a dictionary even though it only has 1 key & 1 value? Or would it need at least a 2nd key/value pair to really quality

Also, dictionaries seem very common in an API context.  Here are some other examples/question I have.  Example 2:

```
'itemFilter': [
    {'name': 'Condition', 'value': 'New'}
]
```

Is this a dictionary? A list of dictionaries? Or is it a list of key value pairs.  Wouldn’t a list of dictionaries be something like:

```
list_of_dicts = [{‘key1’:’value1’},{‘key2’:’value2’}]
```

Also, does it need to have the ‘=‘ to be considered a dict / list of dicts? Or does the colon suffice here

Example 3:

```
 'paginationInput': {
        'entriesPerPage': 10,
        'pageNumber': 1
    }
```

Is this 2 dictionaries? Or a single dictionary with 2 key/value pairs.  I'm inclined to think it is the latter, since there is only one set of brackets denoted therein

Comment: Why do you think a `dict` with only one key would not be a `dict`?

Comment: 1. It is a dict. Dicts can even be empty. 2. This is invalid code. You are correct with your `list_of_dicts`. 3. Also invalid code

Comment: Dictionaries can be empty.

Comment: Example 2 is a *fragment* of a `dict`, where the value happens to be a list that contains another `dict`. I don't know what you mean with regards to the `=`. That is how you assign values of any type to a name, and has nothing to do with `dict`s.

Comment: @Vladimir Fokow this is a snippet from an API call, I figured it would not be a good idea to post the entire call.  So does that just represent a key value pair embedded in the outgoing request and not a dict?

Comment: A dictionary can have 0 to as many elements as your memory can hold. Dictionary is a  data structure and is represented as in Example 1, it does not matter how many values are in it since the underlying data structure will always be a dictionary.

Comment: @redpowertie I think it must be a dict. I don't know anything else in Python that can be separated by a colon like this. I think the "the outgoing request" is a dictionary

Comment: @chepner I should have clarified.  This is a snipped from an API call.  As a dict is formally notated with its use of brackets and declared as dict = {}, I'm wondering if one can explicitly refer to the code embedded in the API as a "dict" as opposed to a k/v pair.  What is a "fragment" of a dict?

Comment: @redpowertie, don't use `dict` as a name of your variable - it is a function in python (that can create dictionaries like `d = dict()` - so `d = {}` is not the only way to declare dicts). Yes, dicts are denoted by {} - whenever you print dicts, {} will always be there. If you don't include the braces, it is invalid code (it can never happen on its own) - thus, it is only a _**fragment**_ - it is a part - not a whole of a dictionary.

Comment: More precisely, it's a fragment of a `dict` *display* (a "literal") that defines a value of type `dict`.

Comment: You should probably work through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can have an **empty dictionary**:

```
empty_dictionary = {}
empty_dictionary = dict()
```

So, no, a dictionary doesn't need to include multiple key value pairs.

Your **second example** is a list that has a single item which is a dictionary. A list also can have a single item, I hope that answers your next question.

Yes, you need to use the assignment operator of = to define your dictionary with that syntax.

```
paginationInput = {
        'entriesPerPage': 10,
        'pageNumber': 1
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a `=` to define a dict; you just need it to *assign* a value to a name, and it has nothing to do with the type of the value being assigned.

Comment: @chepner that's true I was just hoping to fix Example 3 syntactically